# MySQL on Windows running but not accessible on any level.

Tags: mysql, windows

So, this is a migration problem. We have an old linux server running on a non GUI system. I pulled dumped the MySql Files and the folders off the web server.

The new server we have is a new Windows Server Machine, running on the most recent server version. 2013 I believe.

I configured PHP to run, then Installed MySql. I used the standard settings on the MySql installation.

After installing, I was trying to get a drupal installation running and the MySql Database would not accept the password. (nothing changed from the running installation)

I installed PHPMyAdmin earlier so I went in to modify the password, just try and change something to see if it triggers something. Upon editing the account for the Drupal install I was warned by MySql that the row couldn't be found for the user... mind you, im accessing the information through MyAdmin, so its there.

When I looked at the user information, it showed it having privileges on the database for drupal. When I look at the database privileges, is see two users and not the one i'm interested in.

Back to the users list, I go to my account of interest and I attempt to strip the privileges from the account. MySql appears to crap out. I believe it crashed and shut down. I restarted the server, couldn't access a thing. I couldn't even access mysql through the console. I enter the password and get no response.

Here is the error log responses I got.

The first set is the installation of the software. I then migrated the databases.

```
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2013-10-16 13:52:27 11f0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 3.0G
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.14 started; log sequence number 1625977
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 1a7a7d2c-3694-11e3-a6c1-001018e11594.
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-10-16 13:52:27 664 [Note] C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.14-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2013-10-17 13:52:20 664 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.proc: expected column 'comment' at position 15 to have type text, found type char(64).
```

This is the point that the restart happens a few weeks later. It fires up and leaves me this information.

```
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2013-10-30 14:41:21 43a4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 3.0G
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1625977 and 1625977 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 125876475 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-10-30 14:41:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.14 started; log sequence number 125876475
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'safety Safety_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:23 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'wordpress WP_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'transportation Trans_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'mediawiki MW_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'arcwordpress Arc_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'drupal6 D_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'drupal6\_dev D_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'crm\_drupal Crm_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'crm\_civicrm Crm_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Warning] 'db' entry 'forum Forum_User@localhost' had database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this privilege using REVOKE.
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-10-30 14:41:24 4912 [Note] C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.14-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. A bit out of my element. I miss Linux Already.

Comment: How do you make the mysql dump from the old server?

Comment: Can you double check the version of Windows? There is no Windows 2013, is it 2012 or 2012-R2 perhaps?

Comment: The dump from the old server was made from the console, using mysql dump standard operation.

Also, the windows copy is Windows Server 2013